# Jquery tablesorter plugin does not work in Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, tablesorter

Trying to use the table sorting JQuery plugin in the Django template. Tried different sources for jquery and tablesorter files. Didn't seem to work with any of them. Just nothing changes on the template page. The real table that I'm trying to sort is `tab2`. Created a simple `tab1` just for testing. Didn't work with this table also. Tried to follow these instructions https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/. Downloaded .js files from this page. Didn't have any experience with JS and JQuery before.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <h4>Players</h4>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'players/jquery-latest.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/css/dragtable.mod.min.css"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $("#tab1").tablesorter();
        });
      </script>

    </head>
    <body>

      <table id="tab1" class="table table-hover table-bordered tablesorter">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Sum</td>
     <td>$180</td>
   </tr>
</table>

  <div class="container">
  <table id="tab2" class="table table-hover table-bordered tablesorter">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Birth Date</th>
        <th>Draft Pick No</th>
        <th>Games</th>
        <th>Goals</th>
        <th>Assists</th>
        <th>Shots</th>
        <th>Hits</th>
        <th>Faceoffs Won</th>
        <th>Blocks</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for player in players %}

    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><a href="{% url 'player-detail' player.playerName|slugify player.playerId %}">{{ player.playerName }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.playerPositionCode }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.playerHeight }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.playerWeight }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.playerBirthDate }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.playerDraftOverallPickNo }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.gamesPlayed }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.goals }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.assists }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.shots }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.hits }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.blockedShots }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.faceoffsWon }}</td>
    {% endfor %}

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
    </body>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: #myTable is the wrong table id: you have only a table with ID=tab1 and a second with ID=tab2

Comment: @gaetanoM, sorry for that, it is a copypasting mistake, changed this id's but copied to the SO before changing it everywhere. Checked the id's multiple times.  [Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/LBbe_ziebqVfyw) with the editor window and a web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have been able to find the source of the problem while ago.

I've had Bootstrap JS scripts in the 'base.html' template. And jQuery in particular. So it was conflicting with the jQuery import in the child template.

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With this line removed the tablesorter was up and running.

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another thing worth noting is that you shouldn't put `head` and `body` tags inside of a `{% block content %}` You'd rather have different blocks for scripts, title and the content of the page.

Base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
   <title>
     {% block title %} {% endblock title %}
   </title>
     {% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}
  </head>
  <body>
   {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
  </body>
```

Child template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
  Players - NHL stats tracker
{% endblock title %}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
{% endblock scripts %}

{% block content %}
<table id="tab1" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Sum</td>
        <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

As reported in the [documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Getting-Started) you forgot to include the libraries.

```js
$("#tab1").tablesorter();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.default.css">
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>


<table id="tab1" class="table table-hover table-bordered tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Sum</td>
        <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't exactly forget to include, libraries were included, but maybe src's were wrong. And now I wonder if there is something wrong with the placement of tablesorter()  in my template, because it didn't work after I copied all the libraries from your answer. As I can see it runs perfectly as a code snippent in your answer.

Comment: I've tested JS in my template with the simple `<script>alert('Hello')</script>`. It worked

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the placement. I've just put the snippet with the table and the script in file TEST.html. It's working perfectly.

Comment: It also works when I'm opening my `players.html` template as an HTML file, but didn't work after starting a server and accessing the page through http://localhost.